# Best Document Review/Proofreading software?

Tags: reading, english, grammar

I've been asked to review a 60 page word document that is an application for European funds. The document is technical/scientific.

What is a good software to review the document, to correct: grammar, sentence structure, readability etc.

Comment: What format is the document in. Are you collaborating on the review?

Comment: @EricS, it is a word doc, I am doing the review on my own, then when finished the origial writer will review it. i was thinking a software like prowritingaid or something similar, to allow for faster corrections

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to mention the file format in the question.

Comment: Word has built in review mechanism, are you using that? To enable it switch to Review in your ribbon and activate Track Changes. Then you can choose the level of Markup you want to see - you can also add comments and notes. All of these can either be printed, or you can export the latest version without any Markup rendered. I'm sure you can find tons of YouTube tutorials about it.